# Issue with Boost and CMake on Mac Sierra when install dlib

Tags: python, macos, boost, cmake

So I've installed Boost via brew, similarly installed with cmake and python:

```
brew install boost --with-python3
brew install boost-python
brew install cmake
```

I'm currently using miniconda3 (python3.6) and am trying to install Dlib. So far I can install dlib fine, but when it comes to python setup, it fails. Dlib can be obtained by cloning the repo [dlib_repo](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)

Here I do `python setup.py install`, Getting the following errors

```
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1518 (message):
  No header defined for python-py34; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/userx/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1518 (message):
  No header defined for python-py35; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/userx/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:63 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1518 (message):
  No header defined for python3; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/userx/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:66 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python3
-- Found PythonLibs: /Users/userx/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.5.dylib (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4")
-- USING BOOST_LIBS: /Users/userx/miniconda3/lib/libboost_python3.dylib
-- USING PYTHON_LIBS: /Users/userx/miniconda3/lib/libpython3.5.dylib
...
...
...
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: cmake build failed!
```

So here, I felt cmake couldn't find the boost variables, so I added these to my `.bashrc` and restarted my shell.

```
export BOOST_ROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0"
export BOOST_INCLUDE="/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/include"
export BOOST_LIBDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/lib"
```

Note these paths were found them via `brew info` and checked them to ensure correctness.

I'm using a macbook with Sierra OS - as I know Sierra has changed the way a lot of builds happen.

I have also tried to remove boost and download from the site and build directly, but same problem persists.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should try to do `brew install boost-python --with-python3`, i.e. also boost-python with python 3 and not just the main boost. Do you see a difference?

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH setting.

I met the same problem and I solved it by this sequence:

First I install the boost using this:

```
brew install boost-python --with-python3
```

then I found the BOOST Not Found error when running the following commands to install the dlib 19.7.0:

```
pip install dlib --upgrade
```

So I edit the Bash Profile with following commands:

```
nano ~/.bash*le
```

and add the following line into this file:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local:/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1:$PATH"
```

#### Notice

I am using the boost 1.65.1, which is installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1`, you might change it to the location that you install boost with brew.

after this step, I run `pip install dlib --upgrade` again on both python2.7.14 and 3.6.1 and 3.6.3, everything goes on the right way now.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in my system, except for one difference:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Instead of

```
python setup.py install
```

And I don't see that error.